# How to alter languageswitcher to display as select element

Tags: 8, blocks

I am trying to get to grips with D8, and want to be able to use the language module's language switcher block. I am trying to alter the output to get it to display as a select element rather than a list.I tried creating `block--languageswitcher.html.twig` but couldn't see how to alter the list.

Looking into the module, I can see a function `language_element_info_alter` but cannot see how to use this to render a different output.

Do I need to use a `block_alter` or theme hook? In the LanguageBlock.php, the `build()` function returns an array with a #theme parameter set to `links__language_block`. Would this be what I need?

Comment: You could create own language block.

Comment: @ya.teck I will probably do so, even if it's just a learning exercise. I'd still like to be able to override the output of the existing module.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could override the links__language_block template (links--language-block.html.twig) and print out a select there by hand. You would also need JS to make selecting something the same as clicking a link as an option element alone won't be able to trigger like a form.